# Legacy report application problems with autogenerate fields in runtime

Tags: asp.net, activereports

I don't know if the follow code snippet intend to work in this way, because sometimes we "as developers" try automate creation of data display control where number of fields are uncontrolled and with similar data-binding, so before I review the application some guys left this :

Under `ActiveReport_ReportStart()` event :

```
    for (Ind = 1; Ind <=CM.Length; Ind++) {

        if (Ind == 1) {
            Left = ((Line)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["lnH8"]).Left + 0.05f;
        } else if (Ind == 2) {
            Left = ((Line)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["lnH9"]).Left + 0.05f;
        } else if (Ind == 3) {
            Left = ((Line)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["lnH10"]).Left + 0.05f;
        }

        TextBox TB = new TextBox();
        TB.Size = ((Label)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["tbColorway1"]).Size;
        TB.Font = ((Label)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["tbColorway1"]).Font;
        TB.Width = ((Label)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["tbColorway1"]).Width;
        TB.Height = ((Label)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["tbColorway1"]).Height;
        TB.VerticalAlignment = VerticalTextAlignment.Top;
        TB.Location =  new System.Drawing.PointF(Left, ((Label)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["tbColorway1"]).Top);
        TB.DataField = "ColorText" + Ind + ColorwayNumber;
        rpt.Sections["Detail"].Controls.Add(TB);
```

It doesn't have compilation error when is previewed, also others fields that are not auto-generated are displayed correctly (ReporHeader, ReportFooter), but IMHO I think is better to replace this mechanism by a subreport inside the detail section, of course these fields have to be displayed in Detail section of the report. Anyways I would like to see some recommendations because if is possible to auto-generated textbox or labels in runtime I will have to explain to boss why this code was not working, and if I have to use subreports instead, I need to know how to pass parameter (at least I need to work with two parameters for generate another sql query for it) and what "event" is proper to put script into it..

---

After I discovered that most important problem is to get report format changes by how many field/textbox were added to report detail in runtime restricted by a sqlquery return value, for example :

1. Returned SQLQuery value = 4
2. 10 fields generated for detailed row 1
3. 6 fields for row 2
4. 4 fields for row 3

Detail fields are bound to a SQL Store Procedure*

Report will supossed to be printed/showed in this way :

```
//Report Init
```

```
    
    Page 1 :
                         |field 1|field 2|field 3|field 4|
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row1                 | valA1 | valA2 | valA3 | valA4 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row2                 | valB1 | valB2 | valB3 | valB4 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row3                 | valC1 | valC2 | valC3 | valC4 |
    ------------------------------------------------------

    Page 2 :
                         |field 1|field 2|field 3|field 4|
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row1                 | valA5 | valA6 | valA7 | valA8 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row2                 | valB5 | valB6 |
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row3                 
    ------------------------------------------------------

    Page 3 :
                         |field 1|field 2|field 3|field 4|
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row1                 | valA9 | valA10| 
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row2                 
    ------------------------------------------------------
    row3                 
    ------------------------------------------------------
```

```
//End of Report
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't see a need for a subreport. However, some things are still unclear to me: What exactly /is/ the problem? Also, can you explain in general, non-technical terms what you are trying to accomplish here? What do you want displayed in the report? What is CM.Length? What is ColorwayNumber?

Comment: @scott, I need to create a report that in detail :
1. Datasource is bound to sql query (done)
2. Columns 6,7,8,9 are dynamic created taking in consideration an int return value from another sql query.
3. Per each row in datasource (step 1) could have at min 1 column and max. 16 column, but always report only show at max. 4 colums (6,7,8,9) in each page
4. Report only could grow in vertical way, it means if some row had more columns to show it have to show itselft alone in remains pages.

Excuse me for my bad english, hope it is possible with ActiveReportFor.Net

Comment: I've explained it graphically, hope you can help me.

Comment: Is each row above ("row1", "row2", "row3") a new record in the database, or just multiple rows visually but linked to a single record  in the database?

Comment: each one is a record in db from a specific query (table joins), it is bound to a select statement (returning rows from store procedure) in this example there was just 3 (row1,row2,row3)

Comment: @scott I would like to know if this is possible with ActiveReportFor.Net if not please confirm to move forward to another third party control, my boss and our team is very complained about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to dynamically create fields on a report at runtime. The creation of those fields do indeed need to be done in the reportstart event *or* earlier (i.e. before calling ActiveReport.Run).

However, you could place the same logic to dynamically create those fields in a subreport and pass a parameter too, but in general subreports do impose additional overhead (and an additional query in most cases) so I wouldn't use a subreport unless there is a compelling benefit. However, there is a walkthrough on passing parameters to a subreport [here](http://www.datadynamics.com/help/arnet/ParameterswithSubreports.html).

The only thing that looks suspect in your code is the following line:

```
 TB.Location =  new System.Drawing.PointF(Left, ((Label)rpt.Sections["PageHeader"].Controls["tbColorway1"]).Top);
```

You are using the `Top` value from a control in the PageHeader, but `TB` is in the Detail section. I can understand reusing the Left value, but reusing the Top value wouldn't be consistent across different sections (Top is it's vertical position from the top of *the section containing the control*)

Now, it sounds like sometimes these fields do not appear on the report. Some things you can verify to troubleshoot the problem:

- Determine if there is a binding problem or a visual/location problem. TO do this, just give the textbox a border or a background color or something so you can see it even if there is no text (due to failed data binding).
- Start logging out the position of each textbox and the datafield value to a log file. When you notice the problem, go back to the log and see if you can identify what triggers the problem (maybe a specific index, location or datafield value?).
- Finally, make sure that the page size (determined by the system's default printer) is not changing and maybe cutting off one of your dynamically added textboxes.

Comment: Thank you for your time on aswering, I also discover that work with DiamondReports.exe tool is very handicap because not provides errors in runtime, how ever I was able to create detail controls my main issue was what about report format I was talking about.. it is possible?, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Sorry Angle I didn't understand your question. Can you please rephrase and I'll try to help.

Comment: I've commented just a minutes before, actually I'm facing another similar report building.